# How to update SharePoint calendar using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scripting

I've been trying to update a SharePoint calendar using PowerShell (say I have a .csv file with calendar events in it) and have not been successful. Could you walk me through this action? Starting with how to load SharePoint-related frameworks into PowerShell? I'm a complete PowerShell and SharePoint beginner... I think this is where I'm getting stuck. I can provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have access to the Sharepoint server, if that's the case then the first step will be to load the Sharepoint Library as follows:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
```

After that you can get the default Calendar list as follows:

```
$Site = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Spsite("http://localhost")
$Web = $Site.OpenWeb()
$Calendar = $Web.Lists["Calendar"]
```

I'm not sure how to progress from here as I haven't done this before, but you can experiment with the AddItem function of the $Calendar object. I can further look into this tomorrow, but in the meantime feel free to experiment and let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Awesome - thank you Musaab! I'm having problems loading the Sharepoint library for some reason though - do you need to download it / install it? Do you have any tips on this?

Comment: Are you not running this code on the SharePoint server itself? Because this library is installed as part of the SharePoint installation by default.

Comment: No, I was not going to - I don't have access to the Sharepoint server. I was going to run it from another PC (I was given rights to edit the calendar) - do you know if this is even possible?

Comment: Yes this is still possible. There are two ways, the first is to install Sharepoint on the machine that you want to run the code from, this will make the required libraries available. I know this sounds like an overkill, but this is a clean method and it will ensure you have all the required DLLs.

The second method is to copy the dll's from the existing Sharepoint server, but this is a bit "hacky" and you'll run into issues with the library dependencies.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a ton Musaab! I'll try this out within the next couple of days and let you know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

You should either load the SharePoint Management Shell or run

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

to load the extra SharePoint things into PowerShell, like `Get-SPSite` and `Get-SPWeb`

Other than that, you'll pretty much just use the regular SharePoint API.

Here's a list of SharePoint specific cmdlets

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678226.aspx

And here's an example of how to add a list item to a list with C#:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9396/programmatically-add-an-event-to-sharepoint-2010-calendar.aspx

You'll want to get good at converting C# to PowerShell.